# how to use local javascript files to test on live site using firebug (or Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I've got some custom JS that i'm looking to deploy on a live site, but I want to test it out first.

I'm a third-party consultant to the target site managers, and am not part of their build process, so I can't deploy in their test environments. Since it's a DOM traversal library, it's pretty specific.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get my local javascript files to auto-insert for a particular domain or host.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can edit any live code files using the chrome dev tools though obviously you will lose those edits on page refresh. I'll see if I can dig out some instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Greasemonkey Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox.

This Add-On can inject Javascript for pages with certain URLs matching a regex given in the injected JS-file.

If you want to learn how others are writing their Greasemonkey-Scripts then search for FF Add-Ons that start with "BetterXYZ" like BetterGmail, BetterFacebook, BetterGoogle ...
Greasemonkey-Skripts are in fact Javascript-Files with special initial JS-Comment and a special file extension "*.user.js".

Comment: I just did - but it looks like I can only run other people's scripts... Do I have to publish my own file before I can use it?

Comment: Yes you can. No problem. Every script injected is stored local and you can add new script without uploading or so.

But if you want to inject remote script this is possible, too. Just write a new local user script and there write code injecting DOM elements to load remote script. This is often done to inject jQuery from a CDN or something similar the user script uses.

Comment: I've figured it out, and it's just what I was looking for! I've got to figure out how to solve some namespace issues, but I think I can get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just inject the script you're working on in firebug's console:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'url to local file';
document.appendChild(script);
```

Or if you have jQuery

```
$.getScript('url to script file.js');
```

Comment: 1) because there are so many pages I have to do 2) b/c you can't load files from client's HDD within JS (afaik)

Comment: So copy the above and make a script out of it, just save it as `test.user.js` and drag that file into firefox